# Unable to use "this + ' div.someclass'" in jquery

Tags: jquery

Why is this working:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.btn div.custom').html('<i class="check"></i>');
});
```

But this is not? :

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this + ' div.custom').html('<i class="check"></i>');
});
```

How can I combine this with some additional selectors? How to accomplish that in jQuery?

Comment: can you share the relevant html

Comment: `this` is an element which contain attributes and properties. If you want its `class`, you could use `this.attr('class')` for example. There are many ways you can achieve what do you want, but just by concatenating the element with something else isn't one of them.

Comment: @MelanciaUK plain `this` reference does not contain a function called `.attr()`. You should convert it as a jquery object before invoking that function on it.\

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Well spotted. I'll correct my comment.

Comment: Correcting: `$(this).attr('class')` or `this.className`.

Comment: That's weird, that's not possible in jQuery. It would save a lot of typing. I hate JavaScript and jQuery ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to select descendant elements

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('div.custom').html('<i class="check"></i>');
});
```

Or use the context,

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div.custom',this).html('<i class="check"></i>');
});
```